# How to use UI component with EDK in Marmalade?

Tags: marmalade

I need to extend Marmalade for UI component. Find below my requirement:

I need to user WebView component or TextView component of iOS in my app for iPad. I want to know how to achieve this using EDK? I need to show particular UI component at specific location in my app and also need to retrieve data (in case of TextView or TextField).

Let me know whether above functionality is possible or not using EDK. Give me steps and code template for same if possible.

Let me know of further detail is required.

Answer (score 0):

There're inbuilt UI component in `Marmalade` such as `s3eWebView` for `WebView` and `IwUITextView` for `TextView`. You can check official documentation which comes with every version of marmalade SDK, for more such UI components.

You can use EDK instead to use native UI component for iOS or Android using objective C (iOS) or Java (Android) too. If you want to learn the use of EDK, you can watch the video tutorial [here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HYYEvGCiwTo&list=PLB9ADC502477E4B44&index=1&feature=plpp_video) on Official Marmalade Youtube channel.